# Why/How does `print(*range(*b'e'))` write numbers from 0 to 100?

Tags: python, arrays, string

Can anyone explain **Why/How** this code below get number from **0 to 100**

[**Code**]

```
print(*range(*b'e'))
```

[**Result**]

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
```

Comment: Closing seems a little premature - there's somewhat more to this question than just unpacking.

Comment: @sj95126 - The op is always welcome to comment why the duplicate does not solve their question, along with updating it with what they do understand and what research/effort they've gone to to try and figure it out

Comment: Thinking about this - `ord('e')`  -> 101

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look at something like this 'from the inside out':

`'e'` would just be the letter "e" in a string. However, when pre-fixed with a `b` as in `b'e'`, it defines a byte sequence, which is just a series of raw bytes, not encoded characters like in a string.

You can use the unpack operator `*` on a byte sequence to obtain the integer values of the individual bytes, for example `[b'e']` would evaluate to `[101]`, because the letter "e" has ascii value 101, so `b'e'` really just means "create a byte sequence with only the byte with decimal value 101".

If you pass the unpacked byte sequence to a range, as it only has one value, you're getting the equivalent of `range(101)` from `range(*b'e')`.

A sequence like a range can also be unpacked, obtaining the individual values from the range in order, and that's what happens on the outside - all values from the range are unpacked and passed as parameters to the `print()` function.

So that's why `print(*range(*b'e'))` prints the numbers from 0 to 100. Of course, you'd only ever write it like this to teach someone something about Python. It's terrible code.

Answer (score 2):

`b'e'` is a one element bytes array (8-bit numbers) containing the binary representation of the letter 'e'.  This happens to be the number 101 (`ord('e') --> 101`).

So, `range(*b'e')` is like `range(*[101])`. The * unpacks the one-element array to a single parameter for the range function resulting in `range(101)`.

The other * is simply unpacking the output of range(101) as 101 parameters to the print function.  like `print(*range(101))` or `print(0,1,2,3,4,...,99,100)`

Comment: Note that `bytes` is very much not an array, but an immutable sequence. There *is* a `bytearray` type however, so it can confuse matters if you refer to a byte sequence as an 'array'. Sequences, generators and mappings are all iterables, but none of them are arrays.